# getting error in fastapi pydantic validation

Tags: python, asynchronous, orm, fastapi, pydantic

iam new in fast api framework, i want to create an async program using data access layer
i use this website as reference: https://towardsdatascience.com/build-an-async-python-service-with-fastapi-sqlalchemy-196d8792fa08
here is my main model

```py
class Toilet(Base):
    __tablename__='toilets'
    id= Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    gedung = Column(String)
    rating= Column(Integer)
    lantai= Column(Integer)
```

here is the DAL function to get all Toilet object

```
async def get_all_toilets(self)-> List[Toilet]:
        q=await self.db_session.execute(select(Toilet).order_by(Toilet.id))
        return q.scalars().all
```

and here is the main function to be called from web

```
@app.get("/toilets")
async def get_all_toilets()-> List[Toilet]:
    async with async_session() as session:
        async with session.begin():
            toilet_dal=ToiletDAL(session)
            return await toilet_dal.get_all_toilets()
```

i have followed the function as same as the tutorial but i keep getting error:

`raise fastapi.exceptions.FastAPIError( fastapi.exceptions.FastAPIError: Invalid args for response field! Hint: check that typing.List[models.Toilet] is a valid Pydantic field type. If you are using a return type annotation that is not a valid Pydantic field (e.g. Union[Response, dict, None]) you can disable generating the response model from the type annotation with the path operation decorator parameter response_model=None. Read more: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/`

i think its because the blog i follow as tutorial is from 2021 and some thing have changed/updated, how should i fix this error?

i have try to add ORM with BaseModel in the main function:

```
class Toilet(BaseModel):
    gedung :str
    rating:int
    lantai:int

    class Config:
        orm_mode= True
```

but i also get error in runtime:
`pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Toilet response value is not a valid list (type=type_error.list)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `response_model=None` in path operation.

like below:

```
@app.get("/toilets", response_model=None)
async def get_all_toilets()-> List[Toilet]:
    async with async_session() as session:
         async with session.begin():
             toilet_dal=ToiletDAL(session)
             return await toilet_dal.get_all_toilets()
```